# Wordpress custom url from plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to create url from plugin. for example. A new url would be http://example.com/slug-set-from-plugin which will output contents from plugin methods. Is it doable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [Rewrite API](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/), in your case: [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). See [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54583/how-can-i-use-wordpress-functions-in-my-stylesheet/54612#54612) for detailed instructions.